# Jumpy animations in eclipse after installing ubuntu 12.04 detailed (x-post from askubuntu.com)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ubuntu

System specs and code sample in the end of this contribution!

First of all, I am new to this forum. Please tell me if there is anything wrong with the layout or the question itself. I am also new to linux, ubuntu and kind of a newbie at java. I was using windows 7 before ubuntu. The problem appeared first after installing ubuntu on my machine.

**Problem**

When running animation windows in eclipse, using the swing package or java applet - **the animation is jumpy and not smooth.** I will show you a sample from my code of a very simple program that consists of a JPanel and a JFrame with a background and a 2d-ball moving from left to right. The program is set to repaint every 30 ms. It shouldn't be a problem to run simple graphics like this. 
Eclipse is fast and smooth otherwise. Would appreciate any help or advice, if someone has encountered something like this before!

Edit:

Adding an exception: When i hover with my mouse ( and keep moving it )  over the application window  the animation stops beeing jumpy. when i stop moving, it starts beeing not smooth and jumpy again. Anyone heard of this?

**What i tried**

*searching for bugs or problems related to this, but not finding any

*Installing the latest versions of Eclipse and the latest JDK

*Editing my eclipse.ini file

*running my code  on My Windows 7 machine (Works fine)

*installing bumblebee and using nvidia optimus

**System**

OS: Ubuntu  12.04 (precise) 64-bit

Memory: 5.6 GiB, Processor intel Core 2.5 GHz x 4 CPU

Eclipse Juno 4.2.0

java -version brings me

```
$ -java version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

lspci | grep VGA brings me

```
00:02:0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics    Controller    (rev 09)
```

my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
 -product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs

-Xincgc

-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-Xmn128m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss2m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

**Code sample**

```
 /////////Sample from the JPanel class (extends JPanel)/////////
 private int y = 200;
 private int x = 0;

 public testPanel() {
     setVisible(true);
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 400));
     setBackground(Color.black);
 }

 public void move() {
     x = x + 2;
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.setColor(Color.green);
     g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
 }
 }

 ///////Sample from the JFrame class (extends JFrame)/////////

 private testPanel thePanel = new testPanel();
 private Timer t = new Timer(30, this);



 public testFrame() {
     add(thePanel);
     setVisible(true);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     pack();
     t.start();

 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     thePanel.move();
     repaint();
 }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that TestPanel extends from JPanel and testFrame extends from JFrame

Comment: Correct, will add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is not an answer *per se* - just a bunch of observations).

I've been playing around with this on Mac OSX and I do notice that it starts out with a stutter, but it smooths about before the ball bounces back.

This could be to do with JIT optimization, even possibly GC interaction as the system stabilizes.

Try the code and let me know if it gitters for more then 2-3 cycles (the ball will bounce).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleAnimation();
    }

    public SimpleAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int xPos = 0;
        private int xDelta = 2;
        protected static final int RADIUS = 40;

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xPos += xDelta;
                    if (xPos + RADIUS > getWidth()) {
                        xPos = getWidth() - RADIUS;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (xPos < 0) {
                        xPos = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }

            });
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(750, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            int x = xPos;
            int y = (getHeight() - RADIUS) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, RADIUS, RADIUS);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hello mate! your code is running perfect all the way through. (maybe a little glitter but barely noticeable). I Can't really see what you did to make it run smooth but i will take a closer look at it later. Thanks

Comment: +1 for wholesale `RenderingHints`; on Mac OS X, for [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel), use `Instruments.app` to see more.

Comment: @user2315551: `JPanel` is double buffered by default.

Comment: @user2315551 the two major differences that I can see are 1- I using 40 milliseconds instead of 30 and 2- I'm calling repaint on the panel it self, not the frame

Comment: I tried replacing bits of code and i found that this line `g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);` was deciding. Any idea why? I thought you used that command to make objects less fuzzy?

Comment: It will the graphics engine to blur the lines around the object, meaning that it will help it make the object appear to move in fractions of pixels, instead of whole pixels...essentially, it's an illusion, but so is animation ;)